# How to retrieve the pretext before an array in iOS Objective C (parse)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Array object at index 0---:

```
 <Merchandise:AW9JgReRyQ:(null)>
 {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x201b2590>\"; 
    CoverPhotos = "<ItemPhotos:L5ln3ZN5rm>\";
    item = ugh;
    listingprice = 356;
    originalprice = "25)";
    user = "<PFUser:KdRfesAJA3>";
},
```

I have implemented my iOS app using **Parse.com**

In that I have an **array of objects (Array of dictionaries)**

in those I have print the 1st object of that array..

I have some pre text **Merchandise:AW9JgReRyQ:(null** before every object / dictionary which is related to object id

i want to get the preText "  **Merchandise:AW9JgReRyQ:(null)** " or atleast **"AW9JgReRyQ"**

How to do ..>?

Total entire array of all objects is

array-------

```
(
    "<Merchandise:AW9JgReRyQ:(null)> 

    {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x201b2590>\";\n    CoverPhotos = \"<ItemPhotos:L5ln3ZN5rm>\";\n    Photos = \"<PFRelation: 0x201bff80>(<00000000>.(null) -> ItemPhotos)\";\n    brand = \"Baby Gap\";\n    description = \"\\nFight\";\n    item = ugh;\n    listingprice = 356;\n    originalprice = \"25)\";\n    user = \"<PFUser:KdRfesAJA3>\";\n}",


    "<Merchandise:bMPFijErWI:(null)> 

    {\n    ACL = \"<PFACL: 0x201a2300>\";\n    CoverPhotos = \"<ItemPhotos:4pm7vX7q26>\";\n    Photos = \"<PFRelation: 0x2019a490>(<00000000>.(null) -> ItemPhotos)\";\n    brand = \"3 Pommes\";\n    description = Sett;\n    item = udder;\n    listingprice = 245;\n    originalprice = 245;\n    user = \"<PFUser:KdRfesAJA3>\";\n}"

)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have two options for this. Either parse each one out into a string (definitely the less elegant/way uglier way). Or also it looks more likely that it could be an array of arrays that contain a string and dictionary.

If it ends up being the second option, you could easily just grab the object at index 0 twice to get the preText your looking for. However, if thats no avail..then you can just go for it like so:

```
//Convert your object into an NSString
NSString *converted = (NSString*)[yourArray objectAtIndex:i];
//Or..your may need to do NSString *converted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSArray *firstSplitterArray = [converted componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];//split by <
NSString *partialSplit = [splitterArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *secondSplitterArray = [partialSplit componentsSeparatedByString:@">"];//split by >
NSString *yourPreText = [secondSplitterArray objectAtIndex:0];//final step

//now yourPreText should equal Merchandise:AW9JgReRyQ:(null)
```

I wrote this according to your first code snippet. If there is actually a leading quotation mark or something, you'll need to change your indexes. But this gives you the idea. Just do some print statements to verify your arrays at each step and you will be good to go. Not the cleanest, but if your in a pinch this could work.